# must be convertible to a buffer, not QueryDict Django

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, django-rest-framework

i'm using Django rest_framework in the project that will accept a request which is in multipart/form-data and then have to forward the same request data to a new url.

I used the MultiPart Parser using which I'm getting the request object.

I'm sending a new request which has the body =request.data(QueryDict object) using httplib2 library.
the QueryDict object looks like below:

```
> <QueryDict: {u'input_values': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: inputs.json
> (application/octet-stream)>], u'app_template':
> [<InMemoryUploadedFile: app.zip (application/octet-stream)>]}>
```

How can I convert the QueryDict to a proper request body in order to forward the request with the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
import from poster multipart_encode
register_openers()
    datagen,headers=multipart_encode(dict(request.FILES.iterlists()))
    requestData="".join(datagen)
```

You can use the requestData as body to send the request.